# ¿Qué hacer con las ediciones de preguntas que añaden el código, hechas por alguien que no es el OP?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Me he encontrado con el caso de que el OP publica en la pregunta un enlace donde está el código, y al rato aparece una edición de la pregunta hecha por un usuario que no es el OP añadiendo el código que está en el enlace que ha publicado el OP.

¿Qué se debe hacer en estos casos, aprobar la edición o rechazarla ya que debería ser trabajo del OP?

[(Fuente de la cuestión)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/123898/revisions)

Comment: En este caso en particular, fue aprobada por OP.. Con lo cual, es casi como si lo hubiera hecho el.. pero de cualquier manera (IMHO) deberia ser rechazada. Es una edicion mayor y OP no aprende a utilizar el sitio de esa forma.

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, si es el propio autor de la pregunta el que acepta, nada que hacer. En caso contrario, yo siempre rechazo la edición como "en contra de la intención del autor"

Comment: Si, el caso es que me ha salido como edicion sugerida y no sabia que hacer en ese caso, al cabo de un rato el mismo OP ha aceptado la edición, pregunto mas que nada para saber que hacer en estos casos.

Comment: @Pikoh ¿Por qué "en contra de la intención del autor"? El autor había puesto un enlace al código para compartirlo, puede que simplemente no supiera cómo ponerlo directamente en la pregunta (algo bastante común).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Un enlace no constituye una licencia que permita copiar aquello que es enlazado. Si no hay licencia, como es el caso en los códigos publicados en JSFiddle, el copiarlo no solo es contrario a las normas de SO, además es ilegal en los países firmantes del tratado de Berne. En este caso al final no ha pasado nada porque el autor original lo aprobó, pero quien hizo la edición lo hizo violando las normas del sitio.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos La Convención de Berna permite el _fair use_ que sería este caso.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la verdad,no he mirado la pregunta de ejemplo,pero aunque fuera asi,yo siempre desecharía la edición. La explicación es sencilla: yo opino que, o se le explica al autor como editar su pregunta, o que sea el (como este caso) el que apruebe la edición. Si empezamos a editar las preguntas con la información que añaden los ops,no acabaríamos nunca. Además,obliga a los revisores a leer todos los comentarios para ver si efectivamente esa información proviene de el. Por eso,para mi toda edición que añade información,es "en contra del autor" a no ser que el mismo la apruebe.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro *In an earlier case, Sony Corp. of America v. Universal City Studios, Inc., the Supreme Court had stated that "every commercial use of copyrighted material is presumptively . . . unfair.* [ver en wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use#1._Purpose_and_character_of_the_use). SOes hace un uso comercial de lo que aquí se publica.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos En ese enlace se explica que no siempre es el caso y que dependerá del contexto. Y se pone un ejemplo de una parodia (fair use) que se uso para sacar beneficio económico y se siguió considerando fair use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Fe de erratas

<sup>- Gracias a Jose Antonio Dura Olmos por corregirme.</sup>

No se puede copiar contenido del que no tenés licencia (que es propiedad del autor del snippet de JSFiddle) al sitio, que está bajo la licencia CC BY-SA 3.0.

Pueden leer en los comentarios de esta respuesta cómo Jose tomó la iniciativa para hacer la pregunta en MSE: [May I edit a question with a JSFiddle link to incorporate the code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304331/304899)

Correspondía rechazar la edición sugerida.

En estos casos, también conviene:

- Comentarle al autor de la pregunta que falta el MCVE.
- Votar para cerrarla.

Aunque sí se podría copiar de Pastebin (que tiene la misma licencia que SE), y ahí sí vale lo que había respondido originalmente:

#### Respuesta original (equivocada, a menos que se sepa que la licencia de ese código en particular permite copiarlo en el sitio)

Al contrario de lo que se comentó hasta ahora, a mí me parece una buena edición, y la hubiese aprobado.

Es cierto que idealmente uno querría que el autor haga bien la pregunta y se encargue de mejorarla, pero la edición claramente está mejorando el contenido del sitio. Eso es una buena edición.

Habrá quien prefiera esperar al autor y quien prefiera editar, pero eso no quita el hecho de que la edición está trayendo a la pregunta el código que estaba en un fiddle. Además, yo creo que el autor sí aprende de esa edición: un usuario interesado en mejorar sus próximas preguntas puede darse cuenta con esa edición que existen snippets, que se pueden agregar a la pregunta, y que no hace falta usar una fuente externa.

Personalmente, hubiese optado por *Aprobar y Editar*, volviendo a agregar el enlace a JSFiddle como referencia (junto al código), pero eso ya es un detalle.

También en estos casos conviene dejarle un comentario al autor explicando cómo puede hacerlo él o ella en su próxima pregunta.

Comment: Yo suelo hacer lo mismo, dejando un comentario explicando que los links pueden "romperse" y que es mejor dejar el código. Creo que mejora la pregunta, a un usuario que puede no darse cuenta de la existencia de los mismos hasta que no lo ve. Por experiencia personal, así es como los conocí yo :P

Comment: Hay que llevar mucho cuidado al copiar contenido de otro sitio puesto que podemos estar infringiendo la licencia o ausencia de licencia de ese contenido.

Comment: @Mariano Eso no otorga derecho a copiarlo. En este caso no hay problema porque el autor original aprobó la edición, con lo que al hacerlo otorgó la licencia. Pero nadie más debiera haber aprobado o hecho esa edición.

Comment: @Jose No veo diferencia en licencia entre que el autor publique el enlace a lo que subió a JSFiddle o que el código esté en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano Me temo que eso ya es una discusión más de leyes que de SOes Meta. No se si hacer una pregunta al respecto en Meta de StackExchange o en Laws.

Comment: @Jose quizás estaría bueno (pasame el link si lo hacés). Si hay algún impedimento para hacerlo sería bueno saberlo. De lo contrario, sólo veo que se mejora una publicación.

Comment: @Mariano Ahí la tienes ; [May I edit a question with a jsfiddle link to incorporate the code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304331/may-i-edit-a-question-with-a-jsfiddle-link-to-incorporate-the-code) . A ver qué dicen.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias por tomar la iniciativa y preguntar en MSE. La verdad es que este tema es más grande que sólo SOes.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias a ti. Puse un reporte a la pregunta pero me apresuré. En este caso al final da igual porque el autor original lo aprobó. Si se pudiesen retirar los reportes lo haría para que no tengais que perder el tiempo rechazándolo.

Comment: Tenías razón @Jose

Answer (score 3):

Rechazar.

Salvo que tengas muy muy claro que tienes derecho a hacerlo.

En este caso en particular no es así. En [Credits and Legal de JSFiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/meta/credits.html) podemos leer:

> ## License
>
> All code posted to the site belongs to the poster and no license is
> enforced.
>
> jsFiddle are not responsible or liable for any loss or damage of any
> kind during the usage of provided code.

JSFiddle no obliga a usar una licencia, cosa que por ejemplo sí se hace en SOes que obliga a usar una licencia doble: [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) y [ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal). Según el tratado de Berne que fue firmado por los Estados Unidos de América en 1989 al autor de la obra el copyright **automático** sin necesidar de registrarlo y se prohibe la copia de la obra sin licencia de quien posee el copyright.

Mientras no haya mensaje del autor original otorgando una licencia compatible con SO solo el autor original puede añadir el código.

Nótese que pese a no ser muy grande el código sí tiene suficiente entidad y originalidad como para ser subsceptible de ser protegido por derechos de autor. Por fragmentos mucho más pequeños ha habido juicios.

Al final no ha habido problema porque el autor original aprobó la edición. Pero nadie más debiera haberla aprobado y nadie salvo el autro original debiera haberla hecho.

Comment: El [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) permite el uso de material con copyright sin permiso explícito si se va a usar para motivos académicos (entre otros) y sin ánimo de lucro, que sería este caso

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro SO es una empresa con ánimo de lucro. Que se hiciese esto en wikipedia sería discutible. Hacerlo en SO es claremante ilegal.

Comment: Yo no lo veo tan claro. Para mí es un caso claro de fair use porque el OP/editor no tienen ánimo de lucro al publicar. Pero no soy abogado, así que no opinaré más sobre el asunto.